# question about mutually exclusive and independent?

Tags: probability

[image: the question]
Do You think A and B are mutually exclusive? I think they are not. Right?And I am quite confused about Are A and C independent? How could I explain it? Could I do the calculation about P(AC) and P(A)*P(C) to prove if they are independent? I think I could not get the value of P(AC). Am I right? How to explain this?

Comment: mutually exclusive means $P(A\cap B)=0$. Do A and B satisfy that condition?

Comment: you can get $P(A\cap C)$. You need to find the marginal values.

Comment: I think P(A∩B )is not 0. it is 20/100....Am I right?

Comment: How to get P(A∩C) which does not come from p(A)*P(C)

Comment: You need marginal frequencies.  expand the table you have to include marginal sums, with the bottom right corner being the total sum. then make another similar table that displays the proportion for each event. that will be the count/(total sum) for each box.  See if that helps.

Comment: the marginal probability only could help me to get P(A) and P(C). But P(A∩C)...I don't think I could get from the table

Comment: What does $AC$ mean? Is that the event that the chosen person is **both** a Republican and a Democrat? So $P(AC)$ is the probability of selecting someone who belongs to both parties? That doesn't sound too hard. You just have to figure out how many of those $100$ people are both Republicans and Democrats, and then divide by $100.$

Comment: I know P(A)=0.36 P(C)=0.51....I mean I don't know P(A∩C ). I want to see if P(A∩C)=P(A)*P(C)...then I can derive if A and C are independent. So I can not use P(A)*P(C).to get P (A∩C).   Then...Do you know how to get  P (A∩C) from the table indirectly/?

Comment: There are 100 people, and the numbers in the table add up to 100. That tells me that the categories named in the table **do not overlap**. There is nobody among the 100 people who is both a Republican and a Democrat. What does that tell us about $P(A\cap C)$??

Comment: @wen: Please don't edit to make your post incoherent, especially after it is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\cap B\not = \emptyset$ so $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive.  For (b), check if $P(A\cap C) = P(A)P(C)$.

Comment: I don't know how to check that...could you tell me ?

Comment: What do you know about $A$ and $C$?

Comment: I have no additional information about A and C. In the table, I can not get the information about A∩C

Comment: Look at your table.  $P(A) = .36$

Comment: I know P(A)=0.36     P(C)=0.51....I mean I don't know P(A∩C ). I want to see if P(A∩C)=P(A)*P(C)...then I can derive if  A and C are independent. So I can not use P(A)*P(C).to get P (A∩C).Do you know what I mean?

Comment: $P(A\cap C) = 0$, since being an Democrat and being a Republican are mutually exclusive.

Comment: so you think they are not independent???Because..P(AB)doesn't equal to P(A)*P(B)